# converting apache mod rewrite rules to nginx

Tags: nginx

I am having issues converting apache mod rewrite rules to nginx

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried these rules but did not work:

```
location / {
   if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /backend/index.php?a=$1 break;
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't use location, if or rewrite. use `try_files`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have `break`. `Break` means *"rewrite the filename and terminate the search in current location"*. But current location knows nothing about PHP handling (as you can see from your config file piece).

You need to remove `break` and have a regexp-location for PHP files, with `fastcgi_*` directives.

Comment: This is a job for `try_files`.

Comment: Nope. `try_files` is a chaotic approach when you don't really control or handle your environment. *"Try this and try that, look here and there, I don't know - do something, I just want this to start working. If that doesn't work - I have more directories for ya, and I will state them all in this limitless list"*.

Comment: Huh? The OP's situation is [literally an example reason](https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/) for `try_files`.